# Show the locations in Esri Map as dots, not as pin-points

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Currently, my Esri map is displaying the locations in the map as Pin-points. But I want to display those locations in Esri Map as dots (Circles) not as pin-points. Could you please refer to the following code and let me know what should be changed.

```
const renderer = new SimpleRenderer({
    symbol: new TextSymbol({
      color: "red",
      text: "\ue61d",
      font: {
        size: 30,
        family: "CalciteWebCoreIcons"
    }
    })
  });
  
  const dataFeedLayer = new FeatureLayer({
    source: horizonData.map((d,i)=>(
      {
          geometry: new Point({
            longitude: d.longitude,
            latitude: d.latitude
          }),
          attributes: {
            ObjectID: i,
            ...d
          }
      }
    )),
  objectIdField: 'ObjectID',
  geometryType: "point",
  renderer: renderer,
});
```

Comment: did you try anything yet? My first guess would be to change the `text` field to a different unicode character

Comment: As @PaulH suggested, you should use different character in the `text` property of the `TextSymbol`. For circle it should be `\ue612` (see https://totalapis.github.io/guide/esri-icon-font/index.html#esri-icon-fonts for all symbols).

Comment: @PaulH and TomazicM. Yes It's worked for me after changing the text field to \ue612. So, Could you please update the answer?

Comment: You have a tag for ArcGIS 10.0 so are you asking about ArcGIS Server 10.0 or ArcGIS Desktop 10.0; or are you wanting to ask about the ArcGIS API for JavaScript, or another part of the ArcGIS platform altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the **text** field Unicode value to **\ue612**

```
const renderer = new SimpleRenderer({
        symbol: new TextSymbol({
          color: "red",
          text: "\ue612",
          font: {
            size: 30,
            family: "CalciteWebCoreIcons"
        }
        })
      });
```